# How to remove a field from all documents in a collection using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection of documents stored in a MongoDB database that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5fe72e02b237503088b8889b,
    code: '000001403',
    name: 'John',
    date: 2018-12-01T21:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 5fe72e02b237503088b8889c,
    code: '000001404',
    name: 'Michael',
    date: 2018-12-01T21:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 1
  }
]
```

I need to remove the "code" field from all documents in the collection and keep the documents, that is, I need the following result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5fe72e02b237503088b8889b,
    name: 'John',
    date: 2018-12-01T21:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 5fe72e02b237503088b8889c,
    name: 'Michael',
    date: 2018-12-01T21:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 1
  }
]
```

I also removed the field from the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  // code: String,
  name: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

I don't know if it is possible to use `aggregation` and the `$unset` method in this case, or is there another method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result like this:

first you have to add the 'code' field back to your Schema and then run the following code.

after that you can remove the code field from the Schema again.

```
const res = await Item.updateMany({}, {$unset: {"code": 1}});

res.n; // Number of documents matched
res.nModified; // Number of documents modified
```

or

```
Item.updateMany({}, {$unset: {"code": 1}}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.n); // Number of documents matched
  console.log(res.nModified); // // Number of documents modified
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: It does'nt help

Comment: Shows 0 twice in console

Comment: try adding the code field back to Schema again and then try unsetting it and see if it works or not.

Comment: Adding the field back to the schema before unsetting it solved the same problem for me. Thanks @Abbas!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help! happy coding!